# Why does JavaScript lose a day when creating a new date with the year/month/day of a different date?

Tags: javascript, date

Question kind of says it all.

```
> var x = new Date('1/1/2012')
undefined
> x
Sun Jan 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
> new Date(1900+x.getYear(),x.getMonth(),x.getDay())
Sat Dec 31 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
```

Why the loss of 24 hours?  It is easy enough to work around, but I'm curious why it happens.

Comment: Did you try examining `x.getMonth()` and `x.getDay()`? Or the output of `new Date(2012, 1, 1)`? You'd see that they're different and that it's your inputs that are bad.

Comment: I was more curious about how the zero turns into december, and 0 turns into 31st.  Corey explained the Day->Date requirement. It did turn out that just fixing the day -> date part resolves all the issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date.getDay()` gets the day of the week (0-6). What you want to use is `Date.getDate()` which will return the date (1-31).

To answer your question, the missing day is from a resulting `0` value from `x.getDay()` as that day happens to be a Sunday. When using a zero value in the `day` parameter for `new Date()`, the result subtracts one day.

Answer (score 1):

> The `getMonth()` method returns the month in the specified date according to local time, as a zero-based value (where zero indicates the first month of the year).
>
> The `getDay()` method returns the day of the week for the specified date according to local time, where 0 represents Sunday.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Methods_2

```
> x.getMonth()
< 0
> x.getDay()
< 0
```